# No puedo realizar una conexión de oracle con php

Tags: php, oracle

Estoy empezando a aprender `php`, estoy intentando realizar una conexión a la **base de datos** con la que tengo que trabajar, (Oracle SQL developer), pues pasa lo siguiente, tengo dos códigos: `Pruebas.php`, `idex.php`

en **Pruebas**:

```
class conectar{
    public static function conex(){
        try{
            $conex= new PDO('oci:dbname="Aqui Coloco la IP de la BD"/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'usuario', 'contraseña');
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die("Error". $e->getMessage());
            echo "Linea de Error" . $e->getLine();
        }
        return $conex; 
    }
}
```

y en **index**:

```
  require("Pruebas.php");

    $x = new conectar::conectar();

     var_dump($x);
```

El error que lanza es el siguiente:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'conectar' (T_STRING), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in C:\wamp64\www\Pruebas PHP\index.php on
>   line 5

Comment: No tiene relación alguna con SQL Developer. Cambio la etiqueta a [tag:oracle], que se refiere a la base de datos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

Por una parte, estas intentando hacer un `new` sobre el resultado de la llamada a un metodo estatico. Eso no es correcto. tu linea:

```
$x = new conectar::conectar();
```

Es incorrecta, ya que el propio metodo estatico de tu clase te devuelve un resultado (en este caso, sera el objeto conexion). No tienes que instanciar el objeto con new, porque el propio metodo te lo va a devolver.

Por otra parte, el metodo se llama `conex`, por lo que te da error de la cadena `conectar` como metodo, que no existe.

En tu caso, puedes solucionarlo cambiando la linea anterior por:

```
$x = conectar::conex();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias con esto ya funciona!